# Need help in Android Studio: Text alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set 
    `android:gravity="right"`
to align my text to the right. 
However, when the length of the string exceeds the space, the following text can't be seen.

How can I solve this, so that the previous entry will move leftwards?

It appears that the problem of my code comes from `EditText.append()`, when I append the new input from the OnClickListener, the text would behave the way keyboard input does.

May you guide me how to solve it? Sorry I am new to Android

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/equation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="end"/>
```

// Image

The Edit text widget is right aligned.

[image]

When the length of the string exceeds the space, the new entry can't be seen.
[image]

How to change it so that the old entry move leftwards, and the new entry will continue appear at the right end of the edit text widget?

[image]

Comment: show your xml please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this property into your **EditText**

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

this property supports all the android versions. Although @pail kanti also right but  `android:textDirection="anyRtl"` support API level 17 and above

thank you.

Comment: It appears that the problem of my code comes from `EditText.append()`, when I append the new input from the OnClickListener, the text would behave the way keyboard input does. 

May you guide me how to solve it? Sorry I am new to Android

Comment: It worked if I typed using the emulator keyboard. But it wasn't if the text is appended using  append() method.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your **EditText**:

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: The new entry is still out of the visible space after adding this line

Comment: Remove this two lines :
`android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`
Mine is working.

Comment: My mistake your **minSdkVersion** needs to be 17 or above. Check your **build.gradle** .

Comment: It appears that the problem of my code comes from `EditText.append()`, when I append the new input from the OnClickListener, the text would behave the way keyboard input does. 

May you guide me how to solve it? Sorry I am new to Android

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/equation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="right">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: It appears that the problem of my code comes from `EditText.append()`, when I append the new input from the OnClickListener, the text would behave the way keyboard input does. 

May you guide me how to solve it? Sorry I am new to Android

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="....|textMultiLine"
```